# How do I turn something into a Ruby Proc?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreach

```
if j.job_type_name
  j.type = j.job_type_name
elsif j.type.length > 1
  # jty = Jobtype.find_by_id(j.type)
  # We don't want to relentlessly hit the db for JobTypes, Colors, Priorities, etc. so we use the stored 'all' variable
  jty = allJobTypes.find { |h| h['_id'] == BSON::ObjectId(j.type) }
  j.type = jty && jty.job_type ? jty.job_type : 'N/A'
end

if j.priority_name
  j.priority = j.priority_name
elsif j.priority
  pri = Jobpriority.find_by_id(j.priority)
  j.priority = !pri.blank? && !pri.job_priority.blank? ? pri.job_priority : 'N/A'
end
```

I have these two if else blocks and I think they are better off as Procs, but I'm still wrapping my head around what a Proc is.  It's just a piece of code that I want to call often, and put in one place so that I only have to update it in that one place.  It's not a method on an object per-se, but just some repetitious code.

So what's the syntax for the above?

The code that you don't see (where 'j' is set) is an .each loop over a database cursor.

So `Job.where(stuff).each do |j|`

etc.

Comment: Why do you think that Procs would fit that scenario? Compared to normal methods?

Comment: I would say that using a `Proc` would make your code less clear. Besides, there are very specific cases when you will actually use a _portable_ `Proc` or `lambda`. Most of the time, you just use a block in place.

Comment: A very small thing, unrelated to your question: often you can improve readability by minimizing the use of `!` and adding parentheses whether needed or not.  For example, you might change your penultimate line to `j.priority = (pri.blank?||pri.job_priority.blank?) ? 'N/A' : pri.job_priority`
.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for making a proc is just:

```
my_proc = proc do |arglist|
  # code here
end
```

You can also use `Proc.new` instead of `proc` if you want.

You should be able to make a proc and then pass it in as the block to .each, (but I don't see what this would get you):

```
def process_jobs(stuff)
  process_job = proc do |j|
    if j.job_type_name
      #...
    end
  end
  Job.where(stuff).each(&process_job)
end
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but I agree with the author: it doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why a proc is needed; I would think that a method would be just fine.  One can define a method that takes a job as an argument and does some processing on it.